Speedbar does not show up when running emacsclientw.exe
On Windows 10 with Emacs 29.3 I run a bat-file containing
emacsclientw.exe -n -r -f %HOME%/.emacs.d/server/server -a ""
In ~/.emacs file I have (speedbar 1)
The problem: speedbar does not show up.
I tried (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions (lambda (frame) (speedbar 1) )), but it does not help either.
When I run via runemacs.exe everything works as expected.
How can I show speedbar when using emacsclientw.exe?

I found a solution by setting the bat-file as
emacsclientw.exe -n -r -f %HOME%/.emacs.d/server/server -a runemacs.exe
And setting ~/.emacs file as ... (server-start) ... (speedbar 1) ...
